# Quadratic form of a matrix:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the quadratic form $Q(v)=v^TAv$, where $$A=\begin{pmatrix}   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\   0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\   0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  \end{pmatrix}$$ and  $v=(x,y,z,w)$ then

1. $Q$ has rank $3$
2. $xy+z^2=Q(Pv)$ for some invertible $4\times 4$ real matrix $P$.
3. $xy+y^2+z^2=Q(Pv)$ for some invertible $4\times 4$ real matrix $P$.
4. $x^2+y^2-zw=Q(Pv)$ for some invertible $4\times 4$ real matrix $P$.

I know that the quadratic form of the matrix $A$ is $x^2+y^2+2zw$, but I don't about the invertible matrix $P$ and how to find $P$ and $Q(Pv)$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have to choose which of the four options is correct.

The only correct option is (4): take
$$P=\begin{pmatrix}    1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\   
0 & 0 & 0 & -1/2  \\  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\  \end{pmatrix}.$$

The other are wrong because the rank of $Q$ (which is the rank of the matrix $A$) is 4 and not $3$.

Comment: Sir, how to find the invertible matrix P?

Comment: I guessed it. Anyway, in this case there is no need to find $P$. (4) is the only possible option. The other are wrong because of the rank.